# Creating table in MSSQL via pyodbc module in Python

Tags: sql-server, database, pyodbc

I'm trying to create this table in my MSSQL

```
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=LAPTOP;'
                      'Database=DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
              CREATE TABLE logging.t_history (
              id serial,
              tstamp timestamp DEFAULT now(),
              schemaname text,
              tabname text,
              operation text,
              who text DEFAULT current_user,
              new_val json,
              old_val json
              )
               ''')
```

conn.commit()
cursor = conn.cursor()

But I get the error -

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #7: Cannot find data type json. (2715) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

This happens for the timestamp being 'DEFAUT now()' too. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You really must review the Data Types.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   I suspect timestamp is not what your are thinking, you may want datetime default getdate()

Comment: Looking at your `create table`, I do not believe this is for `SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

`Json` is not a data type in sql server, you store json as text using `varchar(max)` data type.

**Edit**
In fact have you tagged the right database platform, your create table does not look like ms-sqlserver.

Comment: I was using this example https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/ to create triggers. It worked in my postgres and AWS database. I have access to a clients MSSQL table and wanted to try the same procedure via python